# How to add new source files to the glibc makefile?

Tags: c, makefile, gnu, glibc

Recently I've got interested in learning the heap management of C (the malloc module). I want to break the malloc source files(e.g., malloc.c, arena.c) into smaller files so it's easier to read and study for me. I'm using the `glibc 2.23` and have successfully built it locally (in a separate "build" folder) on `Ubuntu 14.04` following the instructions on wiki.

As my initial attempt, I put the `__malloc_assert` into the files `massert.h` and `massert.c` but then realized **I have no idea how to add them to the makefiles so they can get compiled and linked**.

Since I moved `__malloc_assert` out of `malloc.c`, I got the link errors when running `make` again, which was expected:

```
/home/mvs/git/glibc/build/libc_pic.os: In function `detach_arena':
/home/mvs/git/glibc/malloc/arena.c:629: undefined reference to `__malloc_assert'
/home/mvs/git/glibc/build/libc_pic.os: In function `mremap_chunk':
/home/mvs/git/glibc/malloc/malloc.c:2832: undefined reference to `__malloc_assert'
/home/mvs/git/glibc/malloc/malloc.c:2813: undefined reference to `__malloc_assert'
/home/mvs/git/glibc/malloc/malloc.c:2812: undefined reference to `__malloc_assert'
/home/mvs/git/glibc/malloc/malloc.c:2830: undefined reference to `__malloc_assert'
/home/mvs/git/glibc/build/libc_pic.os:/home/mvs/git/glibc/malloc/malloc.c:2776: more undefined references to `__malloc_assert' follow
```

I thought I should look at how the `malloc/malloc.c` is used in the makefiles, but I couldn't find where it is used. I'm mainly looking at the following files:

- glibc/Makeconfig
- glibc/Makefile
- glibc/Rules
- glibc/malloc/Makefile

Alternatively, I've searched the `makefile` on [`libc-help` mailing list](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-help/) and looked at all the results but didn't find one that matches what I want. Two of the threads, ["glibc + add new function"](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-help/2009-06/msg00007.html) and ["Adding a function to glibc?"](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-help/2009-10/msg00029.html), were talking about adding a new function to the library, which is not my case (I'm not adding new function but merely restructuring the code).

I'm kind of new to the makefile system and still reading the GNU makefile manual, but thought shooting an email here may get me out of the struggle more quickly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `massert` (not `massert.c`) to the `routines` variable in `malloc/Makefile`.

There are several such variables: `routines` is for `libc` it self, but there is also `libm-routines` for `libm`, and so on.

By default, these source files are built for all variants: static (`.o`), shared (`.os`), profiling (`.op`, profiling builds are disabled by default though).  Some special functions are only intended for static builds (`.oS`, they go into `libc_nonshared.a`) and are listed in `static-only-routines` as well.  Specific build targets can be excluded using the `elide-routines.os` variable.

Comment: Works like a miracle!